# pushing contents to gh-pages with gulpfile

Tags: git, gulp, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to push my blog onto gh-pages with gulp, but when it is in the repository there is no style. [Here is the page,](http://mothil93.github.io/akirothesquid/) and [here is my repository.](https://github.com/Mothil93/akirothesquid/tree/gh-pages)

I have tried searching for the answer, but I don't really know what I can try further now. From what I understand, the page will be built through using the contents in _site, but I fail to see how.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var prefix      = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var cp          = require('child_process');
var jade        = require('gulp-jade');

var messages = {
    jekyllBuild: '<span style="color: grey">Running:</span> $ jekyll build'
};

/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn('jekyll', ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

/**
 * Rebuild Jekyll & do page reload
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll-build'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

/**
 * Wait for jekyll-build, then launch the Server
 */
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass', 'jekyll-build'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: '_site'
        }
    });
});

/**
 * Compile files from _scss into both _site/css (for live injecting) and site (for future jekyll builds)
 */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('assets/css/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['css'],
            onError: browserSync.notify
        }))
        .pipe(prefix(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
});

/*
** Mikael used Gulp. It's super effective!
*/

gulp.task('jade', function(){
  return gulp.src('_jadefiles/*.jade')
  .pipe(jade())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('_includes'));
});

/**
 * Watch scss files for changes & recompile
 * Watch html/md files, run jekyll & reload BrowserSync
 */
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('assets/css/**', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['index.html', '_layouts/*.html', '_includes/*'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
    gulp.watch('_jadefiles/*jade', ['jade']);
});

/**
 * Default task, running just `gulp` will compile the sass,
 * compile the jekyll site, launch BrowserSync & watch files.
 */
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stylesheet is currently an absolute link in your HTML `head`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
```

This makes it point to the following resource, which doesn't exist:

```
https://mothil93.github.io/assets/css/main.css
```

The real resource path you want is this:

```
https://mothil93.github.io/akirothesquid/assets/css/main.css
```

So you need to change all your internal links to be relative instead of absolute. For example for the above stylesheet, use this line instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
```

---

Once the substitution is made, the styles start to show up on your site.

Comment: That did indeed change it. Thanks a lot! Such a silly mistake, yet I would probably never end up finding it.

Comment: @MikaelLindberg Next time you're having troubles like this, don't forget to look in the browser's console! It showed me the 404 for the wrong url, and I was able to investigate what was causing the url to be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Calling a recourse is made like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/main.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

So, in `_config.yml`, you can set `baseurl` to `/akirothesquid` and use the jekyll way to point to ressources.